# Error: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

Error:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token 
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: ON near line
>   1, column 148 [SELECT op.username, op.email, orders.p_id, orders.o_id,
>   product.listed_price FROM com.model.Orders  orders INNER JOIN
>   orders.OrderProcessing as op ON op.u_id = orders.u_id INNER JOIN
>   orders.Product as product ON product.p_id = orders.p_id WHERE
>   product.p_id = '208' ORDER BY op.username]

```
productList = 
(List<Object[]>) session.createQuery("SELECT op.username, op.email, orders.p_id, orders.o_id, product.listed_price " + 
"FROM Orders  orders " +
"INNER JOIN orders.OrderProcessing as op " +                                                        
"ON op.u_id = orders.u_id " +                                                              
"INNER JOIN orders.Product as product " +                                                               
"ON product.p_id = orders.p_id " +                                                         
"WHERE product.p_id = '"+p_id +"' " +                                                          
"ORDER BY op.username").list();
```

Comment: I don't believe HQL supports ON. Try using createSqlQuery() instead of createQuery()

Comment: Also, you really need to accept some answers from your previous questions

Answer (score 1):

Join restrictions are supported by Hibernate but the syntax is not the same than SQL. You have to replace the `ON` keyword by `WITH` in Hibernate !

Answer (score 0):

```
productList = (List<Object[]>) session.createQuery("SELECT op.username, op.email, orders.p_id, orders.o_id, product.listed_price " + "FROM Orders  orders " +"INNER JOIN orders.OrderProcessing as op " +  "ON op.u_id = orders.u_id"+ "INNER JOIN orders.Product as product " + "ON product.p_id = orders.p_id "+ "WHERE product.p_id = '"+p_id +"'" "ORDER BY op.username").list();
```

You have to check the Orders table. orders.orderProcessing is not a table its a column from orders table.

Answer (score 0):

Chetter Hummin is right, "on" isn't supported in HQL.
See this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html